# Resizing UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgrect

I have a view with a `UIImageView`. I am retrieving an image from my server that is 300px wide and 100px high. However, when I insert the image into my `UIImageView`, the image is stretched to the size of the image view.

Code `viewDidLoad:`

```
id path = @"URL TO IMAGE";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

CGRect frame = [imageView frame];
frame.size.width = 300;
frame.size.height = 100;
[imageView setFrame:frame];

self.imageView.image = img;
```

However, the `UIImageView` size is not changing to values in lines 6&7 of my code above.

I appreciate any suggestions, I am very new to Objective-C.

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface detailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the UIImageView's `contentMode`. Look at UIView documentation for `contentMode` to see the different values you can use. For example, `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` stretches the image to match the size of the UIImageView exactly; `UIViewContentModeCenter` does not alter the image's size at all; and so on.

EDIT: As for the UIImageView itself, you need to make sure that your references all point correctly the same UIImageView and that this is the same UIImageView that's coming from the nib. Also, if Autolayout is turned on the nib, your `setFrame:` will have no effect, because the frame is determined by constraints.

Comment: I added self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; however still not scaling the image

Comment: How do you know? Set the UIImageView's `backgroundColor` to black. That way you can see the UIImageView itself, and you will be able to see the relationship between the image and the image view.

Comment: I did change the background color as suggested, and also changed the size of UIImageView in the .xib file, the UIImageView's size is not being changed to the values on lines 6 & 7.

Comment: So you see, you are asking the wrong question because you are making a false assumption. You *think* the image is not being resized properly. But the image *is* being resized properly. The problem is that *the UIImageView itself* is not being given the frame you want. So now you have to turn your attention to why *that* is.

Comment: You are correct matt. I have edited my question. The long hours infront of the computer must be getting to me.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is make sure that your references are really references. You have two references to the image view: `imageView` and `self.imageView`. You need to make sure they are (1) not nil, and (2) references to the exact same image view. Then you need to make sure that (3) they are references to the image view that is coming from the nib.

Comment: Then, if that's working, you must ask yourself whether your nib/storyboard has Autolayout turned on. If it does, your attempt to change the frame manually is doomed to failure, because the constraints in the nib/storyboard will set the frame for you every time layout occurs, which happens *after* `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thanks, I decided to add the whole image view pragmatically and that solved the problem. I guess I had a problem with the referencing. Please add you last comment as an answer so I can accept it and thanks for your help

Comment: You wouldn't like to show the code you *were* using, would you? I might be able to help you work out what was wrong with it.

Comment: It's better if you really understand, and not "guess" about the referencing... Programming by guesswork is not programming.

Comment: Matt you are correct, and I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I have added my header file code to my question to show my referencing to the UIImageView

Comment: Not enough info. Are you also synthesizing `imageView`? Even more important, did you hook up the outlet in the nib correctly?